# strtotime subtraction not working

Tags: php

I have this PHP code:

```
echo "time30: ".$time30.'<br />';

echo "time: ".$time.'<br />';

echo date("s",strtotime($time) - strtotime($time30));
```

Which is returning:

```
time30: 15/09/2015 20:27:16
time: 15/09/2015 21:08:41
00
```

Why is it not returning the difference instead of `00`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using

```
$time30= '15/09/2015 20:27:16';
$time= '15/09/2015 21:08:41';
```

use

```
$time30= '2015-09-15 20:27:16';
$time= '2015-09-15 21:08:41';
```

Format has to be correct http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Note : Another way it will work is by changing format from 15/09/2015 20:27:16 to 15-09-2015 20:27:16

Comment: I actually did it that way ha!

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting 2 timestamps doesn't get you a timestamp.  It gets you the *difference* between them.  You are then trying to read that difference as a timestamp (or an *exact* moment in time), and it just to happens to have a "seconds" value of `0`.

If you want the number of *seconds* between these two times, then you just need to do:

```
echo strtotime($time) - strtotime($time30);
```

P.S. `15/09/2015 20:27:16` is not a format that `strtotime` recognizes.  I suggest you use `DateTime` objects for this task.

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '15/09/2015 21:08:41');
$time30 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '15/09/2015 20:27:16');

$diff = $time->diff($time30);

$minutes = ($diff->days*24*60) + ($diff->h*60) + ($diff->i);
$seconds = ($minutes*60) + $diff->s;

echo $seconds;  // 2485 (which is 41 minutes, 25 seconds)
```